# Нужно перейти обратно из файла php в файл index.html

Tags: php, html

с index.html по submit перехожу в 1.php, решаю задачи формы и далее нужно вернуться в .html. пока был на денвере это решалось так:

```
include("../../index.html");
```

Перешел на Open Server и include() работать перестал. Добился перехода вот так:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/index.html");
```

Но при этом html загружается без стилей и остается по адресу php файла.
Пробовал:

```
header ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/index.html");
```

так же html загружается без стилей и остается по адресу php файла.
Подскажите как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Может вместо добавления файла со всей разметкой выполнить авто переход по адресу?

Примерно так:

```
<meta http-equiv = "Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL = /index.php">
```

В CONTENT первое значение - таймер в секундах, второй - ссыль :)

И да, GET через неё передавать можно.

Подробнее можно покурить [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/content/metategi).

Answer (score 0):

Если в php не выводился код то добавьте

```html
header("Location: ..");
```

Если нужно сделать линк то делайте через

```html
<a href="/">вернуться</a>
```